# How to retrieve a sub document array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongodb like this:

```
 db.country_list.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53917321ccbc96175d7a808b"),
"countries" : [
    {
        "countryName" : "Afghanistan",
        "iso3" : "AFG",
        "callingCode" : "93"
    },
    {
        "countryName" : "Aland Islands",
        "iso3" : "ALA",
        "callingCode" : "358"
    },
    {
        "countryName" : "Albania",
        "iso3" : "ALB",
        "callingCode" : "355"
    }
              ]
}
```

like that i have 100 country details

i want to retrieve a country name where the calling code is `355`.
I have tried like this

```
db.country_list.find({countries: {$elemMatch :{ 'callingCode':'355'} } } )
```

and like this

```
 db.country_list.find({'countries.callingCode':'355'}).pretty()
```

but i am getting all records.How to get a specific record .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator:

```js
db.country_list.find(
   { "countries": { "$elemMatch" :{ "callingCode":"355"} } }
   { "countries.$": 1 }
)
```

Or even with the other syntax you tried:

```js
db.country_list.find(
   { "countries.callingCode": "355"}
   { "countries.$": 1 }
)
```

This is because a "query" matches documents and is not a filter for the array *contained* in those documents. So the second argument there projects the field with the "position" that was matched on the query side.

If you need to match more than one array element, then you use the aggregation framework which has more flexibility:

```js
db.country_list.aggregate([

    // Matches the documents that "contain" the match
    { "$match": {
        "countries.callingCode": "355"
    }},

    // Unwind the array to de-normalize as documents
    { "$unwind": "$countries" },

    // Match to "filter" the array content
    { "$match": {
        "countries.callingCode": "355"
    }},

    // Group back if you want an array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "countries": { "$push": "$countries" }
    }}
])
```

Or with MongoDB 2.6 or greater you can do this without the **`$unwind`** and **`$group`**:

```js
db.country_list.aggregate([

    // Matches the documents that "contain" the match
    { "$match": {
        "countries.callingCode": "355"
    }},

    // Project with "$map" to filter
    { "$project": {
        "countries": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$countries",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": { 
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$el.callingCode", "355" ] }
                            "$$el",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}

])
```

Comment: It is really very useful answer for mogodb learners.Thanks once again

Comment: What if the condition matches multiple sub documents, If the first one only comes in that situation how to get all that mathced...?

Comment: @Mulagala This does match multiple sub-documents, which is the point and where this differs from the positional `$` operator and `$elemMatch` in projection where you can match only one. This is kind of an old question (even if your own). So if you really need further clarification then as a new one.